# Updating Wordpress: Why use git instead of ssh?

Tags: wordpress, git, ssh, web-deployment

Have a wordpress installation on a server.  The server does not allow FTP access so updates to Wordpress are done via ssh.  This is easy for wordpress users to do.

Wordpress is also deployed via git.  It can be updated by the sysadmin easily (but not as easily as ssh).

Why would it be a good idea to use git deployment by the sysadmin instead of SSH upgrading by the wordpress users?  Security is the main concern.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're worried about is security, you're asking the wrong question - git implements revision control (it records the change history), and does not change security.

Furthermore, you can use git over e.g. ssh, giving you the same security level as ssh without git.